# What is a relation between the mixing time of a Markov chain and the diameter of its graph?

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains

Given a finite graph $G=(V,E)$ of bounded degree $d$, consider a doubly-stochastic Markov chain on $G$ as a random walk on $G$.

> If the diameter of $G$ is $\Delta\in O(\text{poly}\:d)$, is that enough to say that the mixing time of the walk is also polynomial in $d$?  Or are there harder requirements to be met for the mixing time to also be polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such infinite family of connected graphs: if the degrees of the nodes are bounded by $d\geq2$, then at distance $\leq k$ of a node there are at most $\frac{d^{k+1}-1}{d-1}$ distinct vertices. Therefore, if the diameter is also bounded, the number of edges is bounded and so the number of such graphs is finite.

Let's just remove the assumption that the degree is bounded (so that the asymptotic notations $O$, $o$... make some sense). The answer is no: even with diameter $O(\text{poly } d)$, a graph can have a mixing time exponential in $d$.

An example of such a graph is a rooted $d$-ary tree of size $n$ for $\log(n) \geq d>1$. If the depth is $k$, then the diameter is $2k$. Also we have $n=\frac{d^{k+1}-1}{d-1}$ (this implies that $k$ is at most of order  $\log(n)$).

It is known [see [Levin, Peres, Wilmer - Example 7.7](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf)] that for a binary tree ($d=2$), the mixing time is $\Omega(n)$, which is exponential in the diameter. The proof uses Theorem 7.3 which links the mixing time to the bottleneck ratio/conductance and few computations.

Now, if we wish to meet the requirement that the diameter be $O( \text{poly } d)$, we can take $d=\log (n)$. Then $k$ is about $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$, and therefore is polynomial in $d$. The adaption of the proof is easy, and shows that, again, the mixing time is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, for a given $d$ the number of graphs are finite, but I'm not sure that's relevant to whether the mixing time is polynomial in $d$.  Perhaps there is a bottleneck on a finite connected graph of bounded degree $d$ that forces a superpolynomial mixing time.

Comment: For (real positive) functions $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ where $s\in S$, we say that $f(s)=O(g(s))$ if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for any $s \in S$, we have $f(s) < c g(s)$. If the set $S$ is finite, this is trivially true. Therefore, if there are only a finite number of (finite) graphs in a family, we can say that the mixing time is constant (bounded by the maximal mixing time).

I edited my answer, which I think now replies to the question you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks, the binary tree is a good example of what I was looking for.